# ASP.NET AutoPostBack from dropdown with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with the AutoPostBack event. My dropdown"s AutoPostBack  does not work. It worked fine until I introduced bootstrap into the mix.

Dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="namesSQL" 
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="EmplID" AutoPostBack="true" 
    CssClass="form-control">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

SQL Data Source

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="namesSQL" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Myapp %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT EmplID, EmpName, LastName, 
    { fn CONCAT(EmpName, LastName) } AS Name 
    FROM Employees 
    ORDER BY { fn CONCAT(EmpName, LastName) }">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The data source works fine, I listed it since I know someone will ask for it...

**UPDATED**

OK, I found that when I plugged that page into another master, it worked. Here is the master that it did NOT work in. From the original that worked, I formatted some divs to encapsulate the content sections, and added bootstrap links.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="is.master.vb" Inherits="masterPages_subMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Home</title>
    <%--<link href="~/App_Themes/default/subpage.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen" />--%>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/green_m.ico" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css" />

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  type="text/css" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="topmenucontainer" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSourceMainNavigation">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li >
                                     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("url")%>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSourceMainNavigation" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False"  SiteMapProvider="isMapProvider"/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h1>Information Services</h1>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">                  
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can this(`CssClass="form-control"`) be an issue, since it was after you introduced bootstrap?

Comment: I have tried removing bootstrap completely and re-referenced the old css, and it did not work there either.

Comment: Thats weird. Did you try putting break points? Also, try clean, rebuild and yeah try restarting VS..sometimes its as simple as that. But if not, may be you should post more code. Because just with this all seems fine

Comment: I restarted VS actually since I came home. I am still looking at it and I am puzzled since the AutoPostBack is set to "true". I put a page_load event in my behind code with an alert to catch that it fired, and nothing.

Comment: Try putting another ddl on the page and just check if an onchange event for that is fired. I'm guessing some other code is conflicting, you shpuld put entire code

Comment: I did try that. I put a checkbox on another page that is not pulling the bootstrap css and jquery, and the event fired just fine. I know there has to be a solution. I'm not sure what other code is important to this without it being deeply embedded inside of the bootstrap css and jquery.

Comment: it looks like it's something to do with the master file. i will upload it